# What is critical factor of performance in Nifi?

Tags: performance, apache-nifi

i find many factor effecting perfomance,such as,the amount of memory dedicated to JVM heap space,the directory of repository,many paramaters in nifi.properties.

I have no ideas to set them?ANY HELP IS APPRECIATED!

NIFI-1.10.0/CLUSTER MODE

The configuration of VM as pic
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@KONG   There isnt a clear question asked above.

NiFi Performance involves the following critical factors in order:

1. Number of Nodes
2. Number of Cores Per Node
3. Memory for Nifi Min/Max
4. Memory Available
5. Garbage Collection
6. Min/Max Thread Configuration
7. Disk Configuration (per documentation separate disk for nifi repositories & high speed disks are requried)
8. Size of Flow / Number of Processors & Controller Services
9. Amount of Data Flowing
10. Tuning of flow (concurrency)

My advice is to start with Default settings that come with NiFi out of the box.  Then clearly investigate any performance issues and try to determine the correct next steps:

1. Add more Nodes
2. Increase Memory
3. Tune Garbage Collection
4. Adjust Min/Max Threads based on Total # Cores & Nodes

Comment: THANKS.What is Memory for Nifi Min/Max you refer?is JVM?

Comment: Yes the min and max values for JVM.